# RandomForestClassifier implemented in Python does not work

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I have this csv file :

```
name,likes,trabels,rapn,aps,class
0,name1,22,0.3,0.893818566,2,0
1,name2,2,0.3,0.910212895,2,0
2,&#122;endym.,6,1,0.195939375,1,0
3,smok,16,0.3,0.56267631,2,0
4,d,3,0.3,0.01069298,1,0
```

and I want to classify the names according to the rest of their attributes. I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import datasets

df=pd.read_csv('book4.csv')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X=df[['likes', 'trables', 'rapn', 'aps']]
y=df['class']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.7)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf=RandomForestClassifier()

clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)

from sklearn import metrics

print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

It is my first machine learning program. The problem is that when I run it I get  `[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]` and `Accuracy=1`(!!!!!!). Additionally when I check for the importance of each feature I also get `0.0` for each. I cannot understand what am I making wrong. Could someone help me?

Comment: You have an imbalanced class problem. All the classes are mapped to only `0`.

Comment: Is the provided example the entire dataset? It doesn't contain any rows where the `class` is `1`

Comment: No this is part of the dataset. But `class` is `0` for the entire dataset.

Comment: @mad_ I got it. I should have mapped the classes. The thing is I would like the algorithm to find the class - in this case am I using a wrong technique?

Comment: Before making the prediction you are actually allowing your algorithm to learn from the classes. If it contains only `0` class it means that it has not seen any other class type. Therefore whatever the case may be it will always predict the outcome to be in the favor of `0`. You are actually inducing the bias in the dataset if that makes sense.

Comment: I see. Stupid error. Thank you for the feedback. So, in order to let the algorithm learn itself, should I use an unsupervised method?

Comment: It depends what problem you are trying to solve. If you're just trying to see how the data clusters together, then yes it would be an unsupervised problem. If you're trying to predict something about the data, then maybe you could provide it with a new target, where the `thing` you're trying to find is class 1, and the rest are class 0?

Comment: Yes it is a cluster problem. Thank you for your feedback. I will probably go for k-means.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is, if this data set is all you have, it is too small to implement Random Forest Classifier (which is data hungry) or even any machine learning. Next, you have a extremely imbalance class problem, "machine" doesn't know if there are any other `class` other than `0`. That's why all prediction are zero.